# Why is my Lambda function creating two Spot Instance Requests instead of one?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have the following lambda function

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var ec2 = new AWS.EC2({
    region: "eu-west-1"
});

var userData = `#!/bin/bash
echo "hello there"
`;

var userDataEncoded = new Buffer.from(userData).toString('base64');

var params = {
    InstanceCount: 1,
    LaunchSpecification: {
        ImageId: "ami-xxxxxxxxx",
        InstanceType: "c4.2xlarge",
        KeyName: "xxxxxxx",
        SubnetId: "subnet-xxxxxxxxxx",
        Placement: {
            AvailabilityZone: "eu-west-1a"
        },
        SecurityGroupIds: [
            "sg-xxxxxxxxxx"
        ],
        UserData: userDataEncoded
    },
    SpotPrice: "0.8",
    BlockDurationMinutes: 180,
    Type: "one-time"
};

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    await ec2.requestSpotInstances(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error");
        } else {
            console.log("starting instance");
            context.succeed('Completed');

            return {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify('success!'),
            };
        }
    }).promise();
};
```

The function is supposed to take my params and create ONE spot request, but it always starts two parallel spot requests with one instance each.

There is no error in the logs, the function is only triggered once according to Cloudwatch and has a success rate of 100%.

I set the timeout on 20 minutes so it can't be that either.

Why is it doing that? I only want one request, and not two. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your lambda execution role has the required cloudwatch permissions?

Comment: @AndrewGillis it has 
"logs:CreateLogStream" and logs:PutLogEvents" rights on cloudwatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the promise-based or callback-based approach. Using both at once results in duplicate calls.

So either remove the callback and use `.then` and `.catch` for you response or do the opposite and do not call `.promise` on `requestSpotInstances`.

```js
exports.handler = async (event, context) => 
    ec2.requestSpotInstances(params).promise()
        .then(() => {
            console.log("starting instance");
            return {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: 'success!'
            };
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error("error");
            return {
                statusCode: 500,
                body: 'an error occurred'
            }
        })
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for the fast response! That works perfectly! Very appreciated!